# Android imageview/addview outofmemory help?

Tags: android

I am developing a simple comic book type app.
I am relatively new with creating Android apps, so please help me out.
What I coded is probably the wrong way to do this, but I wanted to be able to fling with finger left and right on
the screen to go forward a page or back a page. The problem I am having is, after around 80-85 images the app will
no longer run, I'm guessing due to out of memory? Any help would be most appreciated!
Thank you
(the part that is doing it I think is the fact that I am using:

```
viewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(this);
ImageView i1 = new ImageView(this);
i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.s1);
viewFlipper.addView(i1);
```

and I have 120 images in my res/drawable folder...I am doing something wrong!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

      private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
       private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
       private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
       private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
       View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

       private Animation slideLeftIn;
       private Animation slideLeftOut;
       private Animation slideRightIn;
       private Animation slideRightOut;
       private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

    @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);

           viewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(this);
           ImageView i1 = new ImageView(this);
           i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.s1);
           ImageView i2 = new ImageView(this);
           i2.setImageResource(R.drawable.s2);
           ImageView i3 = new ImageView(this);
           i3.setImageResource(R.drawable.s3);
           ImageView i4 = new ImageView(this);
           i4.setImageResource(R.drawable.s4);
           ImageView i5 = new ImageView(this);
           i5.setImageResource(R.drawable.s5);
           ImageView i6 = new ImageView(this);
           i6.setImageResource(R.drawable.s6);
           ImageView i7 = new ImageView(this);
           i7.setImageResource(R.drawable.s7);
           ImageView i8 = new ImageView(this);
           i8.setImageResource(R.drawable.s8);
           ImageView i9 = new ImageView(this);
           i9.setImageResource(R.drawable.s9);
           ImageView i10 = new ImageView(this);
           i10.setImageResource(R.drawable.s10);
           ImageView i11 = new ImageView(this);
           i11.setImageResource(R.drawable.s11);
           ImageView i12 = new ImageView(this);
           i12.setImageResource(R.drawable.s12);
           ImageView i13 = new ImageView(this);
           i13.setImageResource(R.drawable.s13);
           ImageView i14 = new ImageView(this);
           i14.setImageResource(R.drawable.s14);
           ImageView i15 = new ImageView(this);
           i15.setImageResource(R.drawable.s15);
           ImageView i16 = new ImageView(this);
           i16.setImageResource(R.drawable.s16);
           ImageView i17 = new ImageView(this);
           i17.setImageResource(R.drawable.s17);
           ImageView i18 = new ImageView(this);
           i18.setImageResource(R.drawable.s18);
           ImageView i19 = new ImageView(this);
           i19.setImageResource(R.drawable.s19);
           ImageView i20 = new ImageView(this);
           i20.setImageResource(R.drawable.s20);
           ImageView i21 = new ImageView(this);
           i21.setImageResource(R.drawable.s21);
           ImageView i22 = new ImageView(this);
           i22.setImageResource(R.drawable.s22);
           ImageView i23 = new ImageView(this);
           i23.setImageResource(R.drawable.s23);
           ImageView i24 = new ImageView(this);
           i24.setImageResource(R.drawable.s24);
           ImageView i25 = new ImageView(this);
           i25.setImageResource(R.drawable.s25);
           ImageView i26 = new ImageView(this);
           i26.setImageResource(R.drawable.s26);
           ImageView i27 = new ImageView(this);
           i27.setImageResource(R.drawable.s27);
           ImageView i28 = new ImageView(this);
           i28.setImageResource(R.drawable.s28);
           ImageView i29 = new ImageView(this);
           i29.setImageResource(R.drawable.s29);
           ImageView i30 = new ImageView(this);
           i30.setImageResource(R.drawable.s30);
           ImageView i31 = new ImageView(this);
           i31.setImageResource(R.drawable.s31);
           ImageView i32 = new ImageView(this);
           i32.setImageResource(R.drawable.s32);
           ImageView i33 = new ImageView(this);
           i33.setImageResource(R.drawable.s33);
           ImageView i34 = new ImageView(this);
           i34.setImageResource(R.drawable.s34);
           ImageView i35 = new ImageView(this);
           i35.setImageResource(R.drawable.s35);
           ImageView i36 = new ImageView(this);
           i36.setImageResource(R.drawable.s36);
           ImageView i37 = new ImageView(this);
           i37.setImageResource(R.drawable.s37);
           ImageView i38 = new ImageView(this);
           i38.setImageResource(R.drawable.s38);
           ImageView i39 = new ImageView(this);
           i39.setImageResource(R.drawable.s39);
           ImageView i40 = new ImageView(this);
           i40.setImageResource(R.drawable.s40);
           ImageView i41 = new ImageView(this);
           i41.setImageResource(R.drawable.s41);
           ImageView i42 = new ImageView(this);
           i42.setImageResource(R.drawable.s42);
           ImageView i43 = new ImageView(this);
           i43.setImageResource(R.drawable.s43);
           ImageView i44 = new ImageView(this);
           i44.setImageResource(R.drawable.s44);
           ImageView i45 = new ImageView(this);
           i45.setImageResource(R.drawable.s45);
           ImageView i46 = new ImageView(this);
           i46.setImageResource(R.drawable.s46);
           ImageView i47 = new ImageView(this);
           i47.setImageResource(R.drawable.s47);
           ImageView i48 = new ImageView(this);
           i48.setImageResource(R.drawable.s48);
           ImageView i49 = new ImageView(this);
           i49.setImageResource(R.drawable.s49);
           ImageView i50 = new ImageView(this);
           i50.setImageResource(R.drawable.s50);
           ImageView i51 = new ImageView(this);
           i51.setImageResource(R.drawable.s51);
           ImageView i52 = new ImageView(this);
           i52.setImageResource(R.drawable.s52);
           ImageView i53 = new ImageView(this);
           i53.setImageResource(R.drawable.s53);
           ImageView i54 = new ImageView(this);
           i54.setImageResource(R.drawable.s54);
           ImageView i55 = new ImageView(this);
           i55.setImageResource(R.drawable.s55);
           ImageView i56 = new ImageView(this);
           i56.setImageResource(R.drawable.s56);
           ImageView i57 = new ImageView(this);
           i57.setImageResource(R.drawable.s57);
           ImageView i58 = new ImageView(this);
           i58.setImageResource(R.drawable.s58);
           ImageView i59 = new ImageView(this);
           i59.setImageResource(R.drawable.s59);
           ImageView i60 = new ImageView(this);
           i60.setImageResource(R.drawable.s60);
           ImageView i61 = new ImageView(this);
           i61.setImageResource(R.drawable.s61);
           ImageView i62 = new ImageView(this);
           i62.setImageResource(R.drawable.s62);
           ImageView i63 = new ImageView(this);
           i63.setImageResource(R.drawable.s63);
           ImageView i64 = new ImageView(this);
           i64.setImageResource(R.drawable.s64);
           ImageView i65 = new ImageView(this);
           i65.setImageResource(R.drawable.s65);
           ImageView i66 = new ImageView(this);
           i66.setImageResource(R.drawable.s66);
           ImageView i67 = new ImageView(this);
           i67.setImageResource(R.drawable.s67);
           ImageView i68 = new ImageView(this);
           i68.setImageResource(R.drawable.s68);
           ImageView i69 = new ImageView(this);
           i69.setImageResource(R.drawable.s69);
           ImageView i70 = new ImageView(this);
           i70.setImageResource(R.drawable.s70);
           ImageView i71 = new ImageView(this);
           i71.setImageResource(R.drawable.s71);
           ImageView i72 = new ImageView(this);
           i72.setImageResource(R.drawable.s72);
           ImageView i73 = new ImageView(this);
           i73.setImageResource(R.drawable.s73);
           ImageView i74 = new ImageView(this);
           i74.setImageResource(R.drawable.s74);
           ImageView i75 = new ImageView(this);
           i75.setImageResource(R.drawable.s75);
           ImageView i76 = new ImageView(this);
           i76.setImageResource(R.drawable.s76);
           ImageView i77 = new ImageView(this);
           i77.setImageResource(R.drawable.s77);
           ImageView i78 = new ImageView(this);
           i78.setImageResource(R.drawable.s78);
           ImageView i79 = new ImageView(this);
           i79.setImageResource(R.drawable.s79);
           ImageView i80 = new ImageView(this);
           i80.setImageResource(R.drawable.s80);
           ImageView i81 = new ImageView(this);
           i81.setImageResource(R.drawable.s81);
           ImageView i82 = new ImageView(this);
           i82.setImageResource(R.drawable.s82);
           ImageView i83 = new ImageView(this);
           i83.setImageResource(R.drawable.s83);
           ImageView i84 = new ImageView(this);
           i84.setImageResource(R.drawable.s84);
           ImageView i85 = new ImageView(this);
           i85.setImageResource(R.drawable.s85);
           ImageView i86 = new ImageView(this);
           i86.setImageResource(R.drawable.s86);


           viewFlipper.addView(i1);

           viewFlipper.addView(i2);

           viewFlipper.addView(i3);

           viewFlipper.addView(i4);

           viewFlipper.addView(i5);

           viewFlipper.addView(i6);

           viewFlipper.addView(i7);

           viewFlipper.addView(i8);

           viewFlipper.addView(i9);

           viewFlipper.addView(i10);

           viewFlipper.addView(i11);

           viewFlipper.addView(i12);

           viewFlipper.addView(i13);

           viewFlipper.addView(i14);

           viewFlipper.addView(i15);

           viewFlipper.addView(i16);

           viewFlipper.addView(i17);

           viewFlipper.addView(i18);

           viewFlipper.addView(i19);

           viewFlipper.addView(i20);

           viewFlipper.addView(i21);

           viewFlipper.addView(i22);

           viewFlipper.addView(i23);

           viewFlipper.addView(i24);

           viewFlipper.addView(i25);

           viewFlipper.addView(i26);

           viewFlipper.addView(i27);

           viewFlipper.addView(i28);

           viewFlipper.addView(i29);

           viewFlipper.addView(i30);

           viewFlipper.addView(i31);

           viewFlipper.addView(i32);

           viewFlipper.addView(i33);

           viewFlipper.addView(i34);

           viewFlipper.addView(i35);

           viewFlipper.addView(i36);

           viewFlipper.addView(i37);

           viewFlipper.addView(i38);

           viewFlipper.addView(i39);

           viewFlipper.addView(i40);

           viewFlipper.addView(i41);

           viewFlipper.addView(i42);

           viewFlipper.addView(i43);

           viewFlipper.addView(i44);

           viewFlipper.addView(i45);

           viewFlipper.addView(i46);

           viewFlipper.addView(i47);

           viewFlipper.addView(i48);

           viewFlipper.addView(i49);

           viewFlipper.addView(i50);

           viewFlipper.addView(i51);

           viewFlipper.addView(i52);

           viewFlipper.addView(i53);

           viewFlipper.addView(i54);

           viewFlipper.addView(i55);

           viewFlipper.addView(i56);

           viewFlipper.addView(i57);

           viewFlipper.addView(i58);

           viewFlipper.addView(i59);

           viewFlipper.addView(i60);

           viewFlipper.addView(i61);

           viewFlipper.addView(i62);

           viewFlipper.addView(i63);

           viewFlipper.addView(i64);

           viewFlipper.addView(i65);

           viewFlipper.addView(i66);

           viewFlipper.addView(i67);

           viewFlipper.addView(i68);

           viewFlipper.addView(i69);

           viewFlipper.addView(i70);

           viewFlipper.addView(i71);

           viewFlipper.addView(i72);

           viewFlipper.addView(i73);

           viewFlipper.addView(i74);

           viewFlipper.addView(i75);

           viewFlipper.addView(i76);

           viewFlipper.addView(i77);

           viewFlipper.addView(i78);

           viewFlipper.addView(i79);

           viewFlipper.addView(i80);

           viewFlipper.addView(i81);

           viewFlipper.addView(i82);

           viewFlipper.addView(i83);

           viewFlipper.addView(i84);

           viewFlipper.addView(i85);

           viewFlipper.addView(i86);







           //set up animations
           slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
           slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
           slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
           slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out);
           //put up a brownie as a starter
           setContentView(viewFlipper);
           gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
       }

       private void recycle() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }

      public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
           @Override
           public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
               try {
                   if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                       return false;
                   // right to left swipe
                   if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                       viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                       viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                       viewFlipper.showNext();
                       setContentView(viewFlipper);
                   } // left to right swipe
                   else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                       viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                       viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                       viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                       setContentView(viewFlipper);

                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   // nothing
               }
               return false;
           }


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }



       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
           if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){

               return true;
           }
           else{
               return false;
           }
       }
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

viewFlipper might not be the best option for you here. The problem is, all the images are retained in memory and nothing is being recycled. Also depends on how large your images are.

For horizontal scrolling .. your best option is to use a Gallery. Its a horizontal scrolling list. You can use an adapter to set the content and Android will take care of recycling the views for you.  Here is a nice example for that: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Remember, when you implement the adapter, always first check if convertView is null .. and only inflate a new view if necessary(ie if convertView == null). Otherwise performance will suffer.